# Text with different colored background

Tags: ios

How to achieve the below design in iOS , is any controls available to achieve this. I am not that much experienced to achieve this design in native . Is it developed in native or kind of hybrid technology is used

Please find the below image for reference

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Are you sure that you want to change a text background ? you can do it in more simple way, you can have your label with transparent background colour and just set a background Color on a layer/view that holds it the result will be like in the picture - you can do all of it in IB

Comment: Are you interested in the purple and gray bar? There are plenty of way to do it (simply resizing a view for instance), or the label "SMS quota: 200 SMS", with different size and colors, which can be done with `NSAttributedString`

Comment: How can i achieve with two label and views @ColdSteel

Comment: How can i use `NSAttributedString` to do it @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a programmatic Example (Kind of "Hello World") for you 
(it is programatic for a reason, that I believe it is easier to understand how things are working. 
It is not perfect solution it can be done better, (performance wise) but I choose it as a simple example to get you started (Personally I would use `CALayer` for the backgrounds).

so here:

make a new class as follows:

MyView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyView : UIView

@end
```

MyView.m

`#import "MyView.h"`

```
@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        //This rect is in self coordinate system
        UIView * viewPurple = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, frame.size.width, 50)];
        viewPurple.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        [self addSubview:viewPurple];

        //This rect is in viewPurple's coordinate system
        UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width/2, 50)];
        [label setText:@"Hello World!"];
        [label setTextAlignment:(NSTextAlignmentCenter)];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [viewPurple addSubview:label];

        //All the frame's rects are in it's `superView`/ parent 's coordinate system.


        UIView * viewGreen = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width/2, 200, frame.size.width, 50)];
        viewGreen.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
        [self addSubview:viewGreen];

        UILabel * label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width/2, 50)];
        [label2 setText:@"World Hello!"];
        [label2 setTextAlignment:(NSTextAlignmentCenter)];
        [label2 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [viewGreen addSubview:label2];

    }
    else
    {
        //Can't allocate the UIView - quite a rare problem.
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

`#import "myView.h"` in your view controller

and add this snippet to the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    MyView * view = [[MyView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

the result will be as follow

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for code.  i need change frame based on the usage

Comment: @Vinodh If the answer is helpful please consider to accept it

Comment: Answer my question in the comment , how to position the color based upon the data ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/